# Prolog operators = is =:= == \+

Tags: prolog, operators

Im making a list to remember the different operators
I was wondering:
A) is the list correct so far?
B) is there an opposite of the "is" operator?

```
% Does it unify??

a(X, Y):- X = Y.

% X = the evaluation of Y

b(X, Y):- X is Y.

% Is right and left equal?

c(X, Y):- X =:= Y.

% Is right and left identical?

d(X, Y):- X == Y.

% Does it NOT unify??

e(X, Y):- X \= Y.

% X = NOT the evaluation of Y

% f(X, Y):- ???

% Is right and left NOT equal?

g(X, Y):- X =\= Y.

% Is right and left NOT identical?

h(X, Y):- X \== Y.
```

Comment: `=:=` means arithmetically equal. So both sides are evaluated as in `(is)/2`..

Comment: `=\=` is arithmetically not equal

Comment: *X = NOT the evaluation of Y* does not exist. Use `\+ X is Expr`, if you really need this

Comment: You forgot `dif/2`!

Comment: `(is)/2` evaluates **only** the right-hand side and then tries to unify its value with the left-hand side (which is typically a unbound variable).